# JSON data not in proper format : fetching from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, fetch

```
<?php
    require 'dbinfo.php'; 
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_tracks");
        $loc = $sth->fetchAll();    
        $locations = array_values($loc);
        echo json_encode( array("user"=>( $locations )));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The code should return:

```
{"user":[{"id":"1","Latitude":"12.9555033333","Longitude":"80.2461883333","Time":"06:32:57","Date":"2012-03-13","Speed":"0","Course":"183.92"},{...},{....}]}
```

when it is returning:

```
{"user":[{"id":"1","0":"1","Latitude":"12.9555033333","1":"12.9555033333","Longitude":"80.2461883333","2":"80.2461883333","Time":"06:32:57","3":"06:32:57","Date":"2012-03-13","4":"2012-03-13","Speed":"0","5":"0","Course":"183.92","6":"183.92"},{...},{....}]}
```

I'm unsure of what happening... Where is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fetchAll() [returns both](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) (note the 'fetch_style' argument comments/notes) string and numerically keyed data from the query results by default. If you want the string version only, you have to do

```
$loc = $sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_CLASS );
```

Comment: It works! Its the other way.. fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS); Thanks for the help!